# What is final methods in Magento2?

Tags: plugin, methods

When I read the limitation of Plugin in Magento2, the official devdocs mentions that,

Plugins can not be used on following:

> - Final methods
> - Final classes
> - Non-public methods
> - Class methods (such as static methods)
> - __construct and __destruct
> - Virtual types
> - Objects that are instantiated before Magento\Framework\Interception is bootstrapped

May I know what is the meaning of Final methods and Final classes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Final is a keyword used in class and methods
```

Final keyword prevents child classes from overriding a method by prefixing the definition with final. If the class itself is being defined final then it cannot be extended.

**For example**

We can't override the parent class function.

```
<?php
   class BaseClass{
      final function calculate($val1,$val2){
         $sum = $val1+$val2;
         echo "Sum of given no=".$sum;
         }
      }
   class ChildClass extends BaseClass{
      function calculate($x,$y){
         $mult=$val1*$val2;
         echo "Multiplication of given no=".$mult;
         }
      }
   $obj= new ChildClass();
   $obj->show(10,10);
?>
```

**Output:**
PHP Fatal error: Cannot override final method BaseClass::calculate()

You can find it [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/explain-final-class-and-final-method-in-php)

Comment: as per https://www.tutorialspoint.com/explain-final-class-and-final-method-in-php